# Solving Equation with Vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, plot

I am trying to use Matlab to compute a solution for an equation and then plot said equation.

The independent variable is being changed from 4 to 20, but I keep getting an error when trying to compute the outcome.

If I remove the vector, and just *N* equal to a constant, the script works.

Below is the section of my code where the issue is:

```
V = 9800;                 
Isp = 180;         
g = 9.81;               
N = 4:20;     

MR = exp((V/N)/(g*Isp*N));

figure
plot(N, MR)
```

With this current setup, trying to solve for *MR* in the Command Window gives an error with its expression.

I'm not quite sure how to fix this. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Show the error you're getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Matlab, you can not divide a scalar by a matrix/array, like: 2/[1,2,3,4].
but you can divide a matrix/array to scalar like : [1,2,3,4]/2
so in your code:

```
MR = exp((V./N)./(g*Isp*N));
```

and keep in mind that for diving two arrays by each other you have to use "./" means divide each element of arrays together.

edit:
thanks @Mad Physicist for mention

Comment: But that's not what the equation calls for. You can't simply flip fractions for no reason...

Comment: i think he mistakenly write the code this way. is there any meaning in dividing a scalar by matrix? how is that even possible?

Comment: @phalanx You can do element wise division, so e.g. `10 ./ [2 5] = [5 2]`.